# Can't get a Single

Tags: entries, singles

I am trying to get a Single. But it doesn't seem to work.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I already double checked the slug, and getting normal channels is also no problem.

This is the code I currently have:

```
{% set aboutUs = craft.entries.section('about-us').one() %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the machine name of the section, not the single's slug. Check Settings -> Sections in the backend to find out the machine name. Machine names can't contain hyphens, so `about-us` isn't a valid machine name (though it is a valid slug). Maybe you're just mixing up `about_us` with `about-us`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's solved now.